# How to integrate Thingsboard with Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, thingsboard

I'm currently new to Azure B2C and I'm trying to integrate Thingsboard with Azure B2C. I have followed the instructions mentioned in the documentation found at https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/oauth/azure/. However, I keep encountering an error message saying "invalid request". Upon further investigation, I noticed that the endpoints in my B2C tenant have the following format: "https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize". I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in successfully integrating Thingsboard with my Azure AD B2C tenant.

I'm getting "invalid requests" and sometimes a "Redirect URI mismatch error".

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out-of-the-box. You have to implement a Custom Mapper for this purpose, where you map all the relevant user information to the thingsboard users.

The Custom Mapper is separate microservice. You can find the base implementation here: https://github.com/thingsboard/custom-oauth2-mapper

Documentation:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/oauth-2-support/#custom-mapper

Comment: Thank you for your response. We have developed a custom mapper using an Azure function. The function operates as expected in Postman. However, when attempting to log in using OAuth2 in ThingsBoard, I encounter an error message: "Unable to login. Please contact your administrator." Upon investigation, it appears that the custom mapper feature is not triggering the Azure function. Could you help me figure out what's going on with this?